# iOS 5 WeeApp Widgets not responding to touches

Tags: objective-c, plugins, widget, ios5, jailbreak

I have the problem that in Notification Center widgets touch events are not being registered. Lets say, i have a simple widget with a view (`_view`) and a UIButton with target:self forEvent:touchDown. If I then press the button on my device nothing happens. I need to hold it for a short period of time, then the "touch" (more like hold) gets recognized and the action for the button starts. I've seen widgets where touch events work fine (UISettings, SBSettings 5), what do I need to modify in order to behave like a "normal" UIView?

Comment: i want to make the notification center like normal view.can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out myself. I just added a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIButton. The selector for the Gesture gets called immediately when the screen is touched, and doesn't have the annoying "delay" effect like the UI Objects. I have used it with three UIObjects so far: UIButton UIBarButtonItem and UISegmentedControl. For the segmented control simply detect the x-coordinate of the touch and then select the relevant segment. It should also work with UISlider UISwitch etc. . The only object that isn't working for me is UITextField. The clear button on that isn't responding to the clear selector so i wanted to add a gesture for that, without success.